# Strange GCC Behaviour

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++, c++11

Given the following C++ code:

```
struct vertex_type {
    float x, y, z;

    //vertex_type() {}
    //vertex_type(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

typedef struct {
    vertex_type vertex[10000];
} obj_type;

obj_type cube = {
    {
        {-1, -1, -1},
        {1, -1, -1},
        {-1, 1, -1},
        {1, 1, -1},

        {-1, -1, 1},
        {1, -1, 1},
        {-1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1}
    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

When I added the (currently commented out) constructors into the `vertex_type` struct, it abruptly 10-15 second rise in compilation time.
Stumped, I looked to the assembly generated by gcc (using `-S`), and noticed that code-gen size was several hundred times bigger than before.

```
...
movl    $0x3f800000, cube+84(%rip)
movl    $0x3f800000, cube+88(%rip)
movl    $0x3f800000, cube+92(%rip)
movl    $0x00000000, cube+96(%rip)
...
movl    $0x00000000, cube+119996(%rip)
...
```

By leaving out the constructor definition, the generated assembly was completely different.

```
.globl cube
    .data
    .align 32
    .type   cube, @object
    .size   cube, 120
cube:
    .long   3212836864
    .long   3212836864
    .long   3212836864
    .long   1065353216
    .long   3212836864
    .long   3212836864
    .long   3212836864
    .long   1065353216
    .long   3212836864
    .long   1065353216
    .long   1065353216
    .long   3212836864
    .long   3212836864
    .long   3212836864
    .long   1065353216
    .long   1065353216
    .long   3212836864
    .long   1065353216
    .long   3212836864
    .long   1065353216
    .long   1065353216
    .long   1065353216
    .long   1065353216
    .long   1065353216
    .zero   24
    .text
```

Obviously there is a significant difference in the code generated by the compiler. 
Why is that?
Also, why does gcc zero all the elements in one situation and not the other?

**edit:**
I am using the following compiler flags: `-std=c++0x` with g++ 4.5.2.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but try this: vertex_type() : x(), y(), z() {}

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach This is EXACTLY the code I have in my file. There is nothing else. Did either of you check the code? It has {}. It is inline...

Comment: @Alf the constructors in question are commented out.

Comment: @Daniel: although C++11 is official I think you should have mentioned that your code is intentionally C++11-specific  --  e.g. it won't compile with MSVC. Regarded as C++98/03 the code was (at best) incomplete. I changed the tag accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a long-standing [missing optimization in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4131).  It *should* be able to generate the same code for both cases, but it can't.

Without the constructors, your `vertex_type` is a POD structure, which GCC can initialize static/global instances of at compile time.  With the constructors, the best it can do is generate code to initialize the global at program startup.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and link, but also why does it zero the remaining elements in one case and not the other?

Comment: This answer is not correct. The code with constructor shouldn't even compile. See my answer.

Comment: @Daniel That might be an (unrelated) bug.  My copy of g++ 4.6.1 zeroes the remaining elements in both cases (and also does *not* generate 9976 `movl` instructions to fill in the zeroes - it uses `.bss` to do it implicitly).  I don't have gcc 4.5 to hand.

Comment: @Zack, interesingly, not using C++0x for the POD case **does** zero out the remaining values.

Comment: @Daniel: interestingly, in C++0x, the bug report mentionned by Zack provides the work around --> mark the constructor as `constexpr`.

Comment: You'll also need to make the default constructor `constexpr` and ensure it initializes the members (which may not be what you want, ideally).
(check out http://url.godbolt.org/array_constexpr and have a play about with commenting in and out the constexprs)

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom constructor, the compiler should call it for all vector it create. If you don't write your own, it default to a generated constructor. But as no type are complex, it just don't need to call it. And the array is store as a constant table in the binary.

Try inlining your default constructor and let it empty. Of course, it may only work wit h optimization enabled

Comment: It's not possible to inline a default constructor as far as I know. The code he posted the constructors are implicitly inline.

Comment: It's possible using compiler extension such as __forceinline in MSVC